# How to debug smartystreets api call?

Tags: python, smartystreets

I want to use SmartyStreets API via Python.

Here is the script I am using:

```
# ss.py

import requests
import pdb

authid   = 'jaf110af-b6ae-3ea2-829a-035dcb246392'
token    = 'kAyGAA0rD0lNykcktJpg'
payload2 = {'auth-id':authid, 'auth-token':token}
add_s    = '1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA'
site2    = 'https://api.smartystreets.com/'+add_s

req2 = requests.get(site2,params=payload2)

pdb.set_trace()

req2.status_code
#req2.json()
req2.text
'bye'
```

The API server is issuing a 404, so perhaps I have a syntax error.

Please help me understand how to debug my API calls to the API server.

Here is some info about my setup:

```
dan@h81:~/ks/c/lodgiq $ python
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:16:01) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
dan@h81:~/ks/c/lodgiq $ 
dan@h81:~/ks/c/lodgiq $ 
dan@h81:~/ks/c/lodgiq $ python ss.py 
> /home/dan/ks/c/lodgiq/ss.py(16)<module>()
-> req2.status_code
(Pdb) req2.status_code
404
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things happening here:

1. Your URL is incorrect. Your code shows that you are requesting the URL `https://api.smartystreets.com/1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA`. You need to request the URL `https://api.smartystreets.com/?street=1600%20Amphitheatre%20Pkwy&city=Mountain%20View&state=CA&zipcode=`, which returned a *200 OK* response for me. Notice that the address is sent as query parameters, not in the URL path, itself. Also notice that the special characters in your address (i.e. `+` and `,`) are URL encoded.
2. The `params` you are passing in (i.e. the value of `payload2`) are meant to be query parameters, like `city`, `state`, and `zipcode` above but you are sending in the value of HTTP headers, not query parameters. Send in the headers of `payload2` as `headers` as per the [Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This syntax works:
# ss.py

import requests
import pdb

authid   = 'jaf110af-b6ae-3ea2-829a-035dcb246392'
token    = 'kAyGAA0rD0lNykcktJpg'
payload2 = {'auth-id':authid, 'auth-token':token,
  "street": "1 infinite loop",
  "city": "cupertino",
  "state": "ca",
  "zipcode": "95014",
  "candidates": "1"}

site2    = 'https://api.smartystreets.com/street-address'

req2 = requests.get(site2,params=payload2)

pdb.set_trace()

req2.status_code
req2.json()

Comment: Make sure you still pass the auth token and auth key to the API as well. Also, the request URL should start out `https://api.smartystreets.com/street-address?` followed by the parameters. If you don't hit the API with that prefix, you will still get a 200 OK, but you won't actually be making a request to the API with your address parameters